# How to build vueJs3 Project (using vite), Error : [rollup-plugin-dynamic-import-variables] Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, build, vite

I have vuejs3 project using vite, when I run `npm run build` I have this errors :

1-

```
[vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "src/assets/img/users/patient.png" from 
"src/views/patientViews/profile.vue".
This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
`build.rollupOptions.external`
```

2-

```
[rollup-plugin-dynamic-import-variables] Unexpected token (10:2)
file: D:/PFE/Fontend/HealthAppFront-main/src/assets/js/ipfs.js:10:2
error during build:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (10:2)
  at Parser.pp$4.raise (D:\PFE\Fontend\HealthAppFront-main\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:19728:13)
  at Parser.pp$9.unexpected (D:\PFE\Fontend\HealthAppFront-main\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:17022:8)
  at Parser.pp$5.parseExprAtom (D:\PFE\Fontend\HealthAppFront-main\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:19103:10)
```

vite.config.js : [image: config]

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors . It's unclear why is external entry there. It certainly won't help

Comment: @EstusFlask, because I have this problem : "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details"

Comment: This doesn't mean that you need to make code unmanageable. The question doesn't contain the description of the problem, you tried to put it to the title. You can explain at least why `external` is there. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask